# Adding scala-compiler.jar as a runtime dependency

Tags: scala, executable-jar, sbt, proguard, scalac

I'm using sbt and its Proguard plugin to create an executable jar for my program. However, my program relies on `scala-compiler.jar` at runtime to do compilations. I can't seem to get `scala-compiler.jar` into my final jar. [This page](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/ScalaJars) has some very similar information but I can't get it to work beginning to end. Any suggestions?

EDIT: This is the closest I have gotten:

```
override def proguardOptions = List(
  "-dontshrink -dontoptimize -dontobfuscate -dontpreverify -dontnote " +
  "-ignorewarnings",
  proguardKeepAllScala
)
override def proguardInJars =
  Path.fromFile(scalaLibraryJar) +++
  Path.fromFile(FileUtilities.scalaCompilerJar) +++
  super.proguardInJars
```

That includes the compiler jar in the proguard min jar, but running it I still get:

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/nsc/settings/Scala Settings
```

Comment: No one is going to (or should...) help you unless you say what you tried and why exactly it failed.

Comment: I tried the things on the page linked to. It failed with "scala.tools.nsc..... not found" at runtime.

Comment: specifically, `Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/nsc/settings/Scala
  Settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but is sensitive to the location from which `sbt` is called:

```
//proguard                                                                    
override def proguardOptions = List(
  "-dontshrink -dontoptimize -dontobfuscate -dontpreverify -dontnote " +
  "-ignorewarnings",
  proguardKeepAllScala
)

val cur =  new File(".").getAbsolutePath
override def proguardInJars =
  Path.fromFile(scalaLibraryJar) +++
  Path.fromFile(
    new File(cur, "project/boot/scala-" + crossScalaVersionString +
             "/lib/scala-compiler.jar")) +++
  super.proguardInJars
```

I could not use `FileUtilities.scalaCompiler`Jar because that gets the 2.7.7 jar that sbt uses, not the cross scala version compiler.